# How to get data from range to empty column

Tags: javascript, office-js, excel-addins

I have sheet and data, but I don't know how many filled columns will be in sheet. I need data from 3 to 5 row and from columns A to (dynamic, for each sheet could be different).

If I have data in Table it is easy, but I don't know how it looks like in Range.

```
async function getData() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");
    const expensesTable = sheet.tables.getItem("Table"); 

    const headerRange = expensesTable.getHeaderRowRange().load("values");
    const bodyRange = expensesTable.getDataBodyRange().load("values");

    await context.sync();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(headerRange, null, 4))
    console.log(JSON.stringify(bodyRange.values, null, 1));
  });
}
```

Comment: Your question is pretty vague, please read --> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Note: Used Range is 0 index from the range itself. So if data starts in Cell A1 then Col A = 0 Row 1 = 0. If data starts in B1 then data in B1 would be 0,0.

```
async function getData() {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
        var usedrng = ws.getUsedRange(true)
        usedrng.load("values")
        await context.sync()

        var val = usedrng.values[0][0]
        console.log('val:' + val)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the most right non-empty column, you may use Range.getExtendedRange with right direction. It returns a range object that includes the current range and up to the edge of the range, based on the provided direction. This matches the Ctrl+Shift+Arrow key behavior in the Excel on Windows UI.